# After SVN-update cannot load project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control, tortoisesvn

I updated a project (SVN). Update failed because a file cannot be opened, althought this file is not appearing anymore in the mentionned folder (I suspect that I deleted it with right click instead of SV-remove). When I load project with VS after a MakeAll, error occur:

```
error  : Project "D:\...\ExportDatasetCSV.vcxproj" could not be found.
```

The file `ExportDatasetCSV.vcxproj` is indeed not existing at this place in the folders-tree. But before update I was able to compile code without any issue.

Could you please help me with your comments?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a SVN cleanup in the root folder of your project.

Comment: Did you check for file conflicts? It appears that the solution file is still referring to "ExportDatasetCSV.vcxproj" when it should not be referring. If you have not made any changes to SLN file, just revert the file

Comment: I add conflict regarding SLN file indeed. Should I revert it? I am new to SVN. Could you explain why a revert works? If there is a conflict, I have to solve it using theirs, mine or merged. If I then revert the file, conflict should appears again. so, I don't understand why/when to use revert. Thanks

Comment: If you can resolve the conflicts while then it is great. But if you new and now familier with resolving conflicts, just take the backup of your changes to SLN file, Revert the file (it will take the file to last commit state) and then apply your changes on that file again.